# Generic linear search - can't search in ArrayList with strings

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method with which I can search for a specific integer or string in an ArrayList. 
I've managed to make it search for integers in an ArrayList, but when I'm trying to search for strings I can't make it work properly.
Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
public class Search <T> {


public static void main(String[] argv) {

    Search<T> search = new Search<T>();

    ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    alist.add(1);
    alist.add(3);
    alist.add(5);
    alist.add(7);

    int num = 5;


    ArrayList<String> alist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    alist2.add("A");
    alist2.add("B");
    alist2.add("C");
    alist2.add("D");

    String word = "C";


    System.out.println(search.linearSearch(alist, num));

    System.out.println(search.linearSearch(alist2, word));


}

public int linearSearch(ArrayList<T> rrr, T wordnum) {
    for (int i=0; i < rrr.size(); i++) {
        if (wordnum.equals(rrr.get(i))) {
            return i;

        };
    };
    return -1;
}
```

}

The error I'm getting is "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T" on

```
Search<T> search = new Search<T>();
```

I'm new to generics and I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare `Search` it must be parametrized by some class.
In your case it's

```
Search<Integer> search = new Search<Integer>();//to find int
Search<String> search = new Search<String>();//to find string
```

Assuming that your `Search` class is

```
class Search<T> {
    public int linearSearch(ArrayList<T> rrr, T wordnum)...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are creating an instance of your `Search` class in not right.

```
Search<T> search = new Search<T>();
```

this won't compile. You need to pass the actual type argument while creating the instance. That's because you can't use type parameters in a static context.

- [Where is type parameter visible?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Where%20is%20a%20type%20parameter%20visible%20%28or%20invisible%29?)
- [Why can't I use a type parameter in any static context of the parameterized class?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Why%20can%27t%20I%20use%20a%20type%20parameter%20in%20any%20static%20context%20of%20the%20parameterized%20class?)

---

To use the generic method, you have to create instance for specific type arguments. And then invoking the method with that instance will work fine:

```
Search<String> stringSearch = new Search<String>();
search.linearSearch(alist2, word);  // Type `T` is now String.
```

Similarly you will have to do this for `Integer`.

---

Having said that, you don't really need to make your `Search` class generic. Rather, you can make the method itself generic, while leaving the class non-generic:

```
class Search {

    /** For generic method, you define the type parameter in angular brackets, 
        before the return type
    **/
    public <T> int linearSearch(ArrayList<T> rrr, T wordnum) {
        for (int i=0; i < rrr.size(); i++) {
            if (wordnum.equals(rrr.get(i))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then just create an instance of `Search` normally, and invoke this method. The type will be inferred based on which list you are passing:

```
Search search = new Search();

System.out.println(search.linearSearch(alist, num));   // T inferred as Integer
System.out.println(search.linearSearch(alist2, word)); // T inferred as String
```

---

**References:**

- [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [How is a generic type instantiated?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ004)
  - [What is a generic method?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html#FAQ001)
  - [Type Argument Inference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Argument%20Inference)

Answer (score 0):

Make the class without parameter T, and define a static function with parameter T.

```
public static <T> int linearSearch(List<T> rrr, T wordnum) {
```

So you can call `Search.linearSearch(...)`.

Otherwise @NKukhar's answer should have been done.
Also it is better style to enable List in the API (more generic than ArrayList).